# Problems parsing XML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a javascript function that makes an http_request to a php file on my server that generates an XML file (see output below). When the XML file is returned the same javascript function **parses the XML (This is where my problem lies)** and passes it to other functions; which do the bulk of the processing.

So far I've been unable to parse my XML document and I can't quite figure out why.

**XML**

```
<Results><!--Root-->
  <Result_Set>
    <State>State</State>
    <Cities>
      <City>City 1</City>
      <City selected="true">City 2</City>
       ...ETC...
    </Cities>
    <Zipcodes>
       <Zipcode selected="true">Zipcode 1</Zipcode
       <Zipcode>Zipcode 2</Zipcode>
        ...ETC...
    </Zipcodes>
  </Result_Set>
</Results>
```

**Javascript**

```
function GetZipInfo(zipcode){
    var xmlhttp;
    var x,resultSet,state,cities,zipcodes

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){  

            resultSet=xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Result_Set") //Function Crashes Here

            for(x=0;x<resultSet.length;x++){
                state=resultSet[x].getElementsByTagName("State")[0].nodeValue;
                cities=resultSet[x].getElementsByTagName("Cities");
                zipcodes=resultSet[x].getElementsByTagName("Zipcodes");

                selectState(state)
                xmlDropdown(cities, "City", "Cities")
                xmlDropdown(zipcodes, "Zipcode", "Zipcodes")
            }
        }
    }   
    xmlhttp.open("GET","GetZipInfo.php?Zipcode="+zipcode,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I have never parsed an XML document in ANY language before, so I think it's safe to say that I'm completely lost as to what's wrong.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: It turns out that my response is coming back as **responseText** instead of **responseXML**

**responseText**

I am using **php** to create the XML page:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
//Create the DOM
echo $xmlDoc->saveXML()
```

Still unsure why it's not returning as XML. Could it have something to do with **echo $xmlDoc->saveXML()**?

**Edit**: I agree with several comments that my problem is with my header in the XML file. 
I added the line "alert(xmlhttp.responseText)" to my code. Which displays:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--The Contents of my XML file-->
```

Does the encoding type need to be set for this to work correctly. And if so, how can I modify my PHP code (see above) to insert that encoding?

Comment: Error in the console? XML looks to be missing the top line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>`

Comment: could you debug (inspect/log/alert) the xmlhttp.responseXML and tell us the results?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME type of your response should be `text/xml`, or something ending with `+xml` ([RFC 3023](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3023)).

Also, you should add a [XML declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-prolog-dtd) before the first line.

And last, but not least, although [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) is available on all elements in HTML documents, you should use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) in XML documents:

```
var resultSet = xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("Result_Set");
```

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your code your missing :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Also missing ';' after these lines :

```
selectState(state)
xmlDropdown(cities, "City", "Cities")
xmlDropdown(zipcodes, "Zipcode", "Zipcodes")
```

In XML also missing '>' after :

```
</Zipcode
```